# How to limit number of docker docker containers to be created per host without using schedulers like docker swarm or kubernetes

Tags: docker

A simple question about docker!
I want to deploy my containerised application where I am supposed to launch more containers, right now I am not using any schedulers for resource allocation. I have configured cgroup as well as namespace configurations. It will only help us to allocate system resource for docker engine. But it would like to restrict the number of container per host. Is it possible to achieve by tuning linux kernel paramters or docker engine configurations. I plan to manage it by kubernetes. But its just for my clarification.